# Set alias of data table pagination numbers

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination

I am working on a project which for some reasons we need to load data in separate pieces .

we load `5000` number of rows on every page load and show them to user.
in first loading we have correct pagination which starts from `1` to `500`(10 `item` per page).

But when we want to load second bunch of data which is from 10000 to 20000
we want pagination starts form `501` to `1000` .

Do you have any idea about how to do it ?

Comment: Never tried that, but [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) looks usefull